# How to pass function as argument in elisp

Tags: elisp

I am reading SICP recently to learn lisp programming.

There is an example in the book to make a high level function ***sum*** as below.

```
 (define (sum term a next b)
   ...
   (term a)
   ...
   (next a)
   ...
```

In this function, **term** and **next** are functions.

I want to write the same function in elisp like this.

```
 (defun sum (term a next b)
    ....
    (funcall term a)
    ...
    (func next a)
    ....
```

Then I define some test functions to test sum

```
 (defun inc-test (x) (+ x 1))

 sum inc-test 1 inc-test 10
```

but it show errors like this: ***Invalid function: inc-test***

As I am new to elisp, can anyone call tell me how to fix it?
very appreciate

Comment: How are you calling `sum`?

Comment: Hi, add the calling example

Comment: Emacs Lisp has two namesapces for functions and for variables. This means that `inc-test` in your last example is used as a variable, but is not defined as a variable (it is a function). You need to pass either a symbol or a function reference to `funcall`. Hence one way of fixing your code is to pass it `'inc-test` instead of `inc-test` (note the quote).

Comment: do you mean this: sum 'inc-test 1 'inc-test 10 ???  got this error: usage: sum : (TERM A NEXT B)

Comment: @wvxvw: could you write up your comment as an answer, please?

Comment: The two namespaces vs one issue is one of the big differences between elisp and common lisp on one hand, and scheme on the other. You are bound to be confused if you read SICP and practice in a lisp-2 (as the kind with separate name spaces for variables and functions are called). Perhaps you should get an actual scheme implementation to play with?

Comment: yeah, thanks for your suggestion. I will try

Answer (score 9):

To recap what is in the comments, `funcall` unquotes its argument (by just accessing the argument). And before that, we also need to make sure that we don't try to evaluate or access the value of the function name parameter that is passed in the call to the function.

Therefore, an acceptable answer seems to be:

```
(defun sum (term a next b)
    (funcall term a)
    (funcall next a))

(defun inc-test (x) (+ x 1))

(sum 'inc-test 1 'inc-test 10 )
```

Or basically call with `'inc-test` or `(quote inctest)` rather than `inc-test`.