# How to call a function that is the value of a variable?

Tags: functions, funcall

Can someone explain to me why the code below throws an error `(void-function fn)`?

```lisp
(let ((lexical-binding t)
      (fn (lambda (y) (+ y 4)))
      (x 4))
  (pcase x
    (10 (- x 2))
    (4 (fn x))))
```

and is there a way to fix it without `defun`'ing a function?

Comment: `let` binds variables, not functions. So `fn` is a variable whose value is a function. You need to call it as `(funcall fn x)`.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks!

Comment: @Basil: Please consider posting that answer as an answer. Comments can be deleted at any time. But maybe check also to see whether the question is a duplicate. Thx.

Comment: I have a feeling this question is a dup. I suggest searching for `void-function`... and maybe tag `[debugging]`.

Comment: @Drew I'm also pretty sure it's a duplicate but I can't find the original.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the original either. But I recognize that the question is pretty basic so it's probably answered as part of other questions.

Comment: Basic, even super-basic questions are most welcome! It's good to avoid duplicate questions, to consolidate the Q&A together (for search etc., in particular).

Comment: @Drew I searched “Lisp-2” and found https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/error-void-variable-on-function-name and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14747/how-to-pass-function-as-argument-in-elisp which answer the opposite question (I have a function and want to pass it around as a variable), but not this (I have a variable and want to call it as a function). While the core explanation is the same, the practical solution is different so they aren't adequate duplicates. If a duplicate exists, it doesn't have a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs is a “[Lisp-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#The_function_namespace)”: functions and values have separate namespaces. A function definition `(defun foo …)` and a function call `(foo …)` use the function slot of the symbol `foo`. A variable assignment `(setq foo …)`, a variable binding `(let ((foo …)) …)`, and a variable reference `x` use the value slot of the symbol `foo`.

To call a function which is stored in the value slot of a symbol, use [`funcall`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#index-funcall-972).

```
(funcall fn x)
```

More generally, but infrequently, the argument to `funcall` can be any Lisp expression. `funcall` is an ordinary function.

Lisp functions take a list of arguments. Sometimes, in addition to calling a variable function, you need to call the function with a variable list of arguments. In this case, use [`apply`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#index-apply-973) instead of `funcall`. The last argument to `apply` is used as a list of remaining arguments.

In this particular case, where the code of the function is fully known, you can also use [`cl-flet`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Function-Bindings.html#index-cl_002dflet-32) from the CL library that is distributed with Emacs. This doesn't let you easily pass the function around, which may or may not be an issue in your real program.

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(let ((lexical-binding t)
      (x 4))
  (cl-flet ((fn (y) (+ y 4)))
    (pcase x
      (10 (- x 2))
      (4 (fn x)))))
```