# How do I call a function within a lambda?

Tags: functions, variables, lexical-binding, funcall, lambda

I would like to define a function that generates lambdas, as such:

```
(defun my-func (FUNCTION)
    (lambda ()
        (FUNCTION)))
```

But when I evaluate the following

```
(defun my-func1 ()
    (message "Hello World"))

(funcall (my-func #'my-func1))
```

I am told that

```
Symbol's function definition is void: FUNCTION
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a function that is the value of a variable?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59204/how-to-call-a-function-that-is-the-value-of-a-variable)

Comment: `(FUNCTION)` needs to be `(funcall FUNCTION)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol `FUNCTION` in your definition of `my-func` has a local binding for the symbol `FUNCTION` as **variable** and not as function.

So you need to call `(funcall FUNCTION)` in your `lambda`.

Furthermore, be aware that lexical binding is required for your code to work (`FUNCTION` must be known to the lambda outside of `my-func`, i.e., the `lambda` must actually be a [closure](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Closures.html).).